# Beautifulsoup Get All Header Tags and Add Id Attribute Incrementing

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Ok I give up. I need some help.

I am trying to find all the Header HTML tags in a html document. I want to find these html tags and add an id to them that increments the id. I need to keep the structure of the document in place.

I have had several different variations just can't seem to get it right.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(blog.body, "html.parser")
tags = soup.find_all()
count = 0
for item in tags:
    if r"^h\d$" in item:
        print('Found')
        count += 1
        item['id'] = count
        soup.append(item)
    soup.append(item)
print(soup)
```

Comment: your `if` statement is incorrect, I assume you want to check for regex, so use `re.search(r"^h\d$", item.name)`

Comment: don't forget to import it with `import re` at the top of the file. Also you don't need to append the item back to the soup. So remove those `append` lines

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do without re, another solution. It searches for all html tags and with beautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as parser

with open("test.html", "r") as readFile:
    htmlSource = readFile.read()

soup = parser(htmlSource, "html.parser")
htmlTags = soup.find_all("html")
for eachTag in htmlTags:
    eachTag.attrs["id"] = htmlTags.index(eachTag)



with open("out.html", "w") as saveFile:
    saveFile.write(str(soup))
```